# Pick wiremock parameter dynamically

Tags: java, wiremock

I am trying to use the body of the request as a lookup object. I can add transformer parameters but then I need to pick the correct one using a json query. For example with this stub:

```
     stubFor(
        post( "/test" )
          .willReturn(
            aResponse()
              .withBody( "{{ parameters.(jsonPath request.body '$.body')}}" )
              .withTransformerParameter( "data", "newData" ) ) )
```

Then sending this body: `{ "body": "data" }` would be able to return the string "newData".

The 2 individual parts work: `{{jsonPath request.body '$.body'}}` returns `data` and `{{ parameters.data }}` returns `"newData"`. I cannot find a way to evaluate recursively. When using the above nesting notation, the error is as follows:

> could not find helper parameters.

Is there a different notation that would work?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question. There is a builtin lookup helper function.

Stubbing with:

```
       aResponse()
              .withBody( "{{ lookup parameters (jsonPath request.body '$.body')}}" )
              .withTransformerParameter( "data", "newData" ) ) )
```

Then posting `{ "body": "data" }` returns newData